# PreparedStatement Insert in Java

Tags: java, prepared-statement

i have written a code, where if a button is pressed, values from textfields shall be taken to create a record in a database. the code compiles but when i run it, i get this error message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From, To, TotalDays, VacationType, Notes, Signature, Date) VALUES('','','','',''' at line 1
```

Any suggestions?

```
    final JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {                 
        try {

            String vacationid = text_vacationID.getText();
            String staffid = text_staffID.getText();
            String from = text_from.getText();
            String to = text_to.getText();
            String totaldays = text_totalDays.getText();
            String vacationtype = text_vacationType.getText();
            String notes = textArea.getText();
            String signature = text_signature.getText();
            String date = text_date.getText();


            String sql = "INSERT into vacation (VacationID, StaffID, From, To, TotalDays, VacationType, Notes, Signature, Date) VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";    

            PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            prest.setString(1, vacationid);
            prest.setString(2, staffid);
            prest.setString(3, from);
            prest.setString(4, to);
            prest.setString(5, totaldays);
            prest.setString(6, vacationtype);
            prest.setString(7, notes);
            prest.setString(8, signature);
            prest.setString(9, date);

            prest.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmBookVacation, "Vacation has been booked for Employee with ID: " + vacationid);


        } 

        catch (SQLException e) {
        //System.out.println("Record couldn't be added!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmBookVacation, "Vacation couldn't be booked. Please try again.");
        }
        }

        });
    btnSubmit.setBounds(201, 350, 89, 23);
    panel_1.add(btnSubmit);
```

Comment: From is a reserved keyword, To and Date probably too (check the manual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`From` is a reserved word in MySQL. Also you can get rid of all those fields from your table in the code as the following:

```
String sql = "INSERT into vacation VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

That should work.

Comment: *"Also you can get rid of all those fields from your table in the code as the following"* Only if you're specifying all of the fields, in the order in which the table has them defined, and no one ever edits the table definition. Very, very bad idea to rely on that. Explicit column names are used for a reason.

Answer (score 5):

`from` is a reserved word in SQL, you need to [escape it with backticks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) (or quotes if you have ANSI mode enabled).

```
String sql = "INSERT into vacation (`VacationID`, `StaffID`, `From`, `To`, `TotalDays`, `VacationType`, `Notes`, `Signature`, `Date`) VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

I've done all of the column names there, for consistency and because a couple of the others might be reserved by some engines (or not).

Comment: `DATE` is not a reserved keyword (at least, not anymore).

Comment: @AmalMurali: Thanks, I've waffled that sentence now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

"From" is a keyword.  Remember, keywords in SQL are case-insenstive.  Surround it in back quotes

```
`From`
```

Answer (score 1):

Some columns names match SQL keywords:
http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/sql-keywords-appendix.html